# Filter datetime from SQL to DataGridView with ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a table `TKDV` in stored procedures has properties including `UsageTime` of datatype `datetime`.

A datagridview to display data from database, a combobox named `cbSelectMonth`, a combobox named `cbSelectYear`.

When selecting the "All" option from `cbSelectYear`, the corresponding "all" option from `cbSelectMonth` will be automatically selected and I will filter and retrieve all data from table `TKDV` to be displayed in the datagridview.

When selecting a year from `cbSelectYear` and a month from `cbSelectMonth`, data in the database with the same month and year will be selected to be displayed in the datagridview.

When selecting a year from `cbSelectYear` and "All" option from `cbSelectMonth`, all data in the database for that selected year will be returned to be displayed in the datagridview.

How to do this?

I tried using array, loop, if else but it doesn't work!

Comment: Populate a DataTable with the results of your query, bind that to a BindingSource and bind that to the grid. In the appropriate event handler(s) you can set the Filter of the BindingSource based on your ComboBoxes.

Comment: There are [myriads of answers to this question](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=winforms+how+to+filter+DGV) already.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you would use event handlers for the comboboxes, and then refresh the datagridview based on the selected values. Here's a basic outline of how you might implement this in C#:

First, you would want to handle the selection change event for both the cbSelectYear and cbSelectMonth comboboxes.

```
private void cbSelectYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshDataGridView();
}

private void cbSelectMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshDataGridView();
}
```

Then you would implement the RefreshDataGridView method:

```
private void RefreshDataGridView()
{
    string selectedYear = cbSelectYear.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string selectedMonth = cbSelectMonth.SelectedItem.ToString();

    string query;

    if (selectedYear == "All" && selectedMonth == "All")
    {
        query = "SELECT * FROM TKDV";
    }
    else if (selectedYear != "All" && selectedMonth == "All")
    {
        query = $"SELECT * FROM TKDV WHERE YEAR(UsageTime) = {selectedYear}";
    }
    else if (selectedYear != "All" && selectedMonth != "All")
    {
        int monthIndex = DateTime.ParseExact(selectedMonth, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;
        query = $"SELECT * FROM TKDV WHERE YEAR(UsageTime) = {selectedYear} AND MONTH(UsageTime) = {monthIndex}";
    }
    
    // Rather use stored procedures
}
```

This is a simple example that might need to be adapted based on your specific needs. It assumes that the "All" option is represented as the string "All" in the comboboxes. Also, it assumes that the selectedMonth is the full name of the month, and that's why it is using DateTime.ParseExact to get the month index.